# C programming: live console display of recursive function output (knight's tour)

Tags: c, recursion, output, knights-tour

I'm stuck at my first more complex coding task in C: developing a program that solves the knight's tour (chess, knight has to visit every field on the board only once) and it also should have a live display, showing which move the program is taking in real time.
The solution I came up with doesn't support live display though, as it is iterating through a for loop until the maximum number of moves has been reached, then prints the moves. How could I change this code to create real time output?
The displayBoard function is only printing a chessboard in the console output, with the current position of the knight as well as the field's name (e.g. A-1). Plan is to change this to a stream output for console, after my initial problem is solved.

(In conjunction to this question: how exactly does the function calling as if condition work? I stumbled upon this in the webs but sadly there was no explanation to it.)

```
int knight(int line, int row, int moveNumber)
{
    int newLine, newRow, i;
    //char cells[]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};

    //mark visited cell
    board[line][row] = moveNumber;
    
    //for-loop for every possible move
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {        
        //new position
        newLine = line + moves[i][0];
        newRow = row + moves[i][1];
        
        //is the move on the board?
        if(newLine >= 1 && newLine <= N && newRow >= 1 && newRow <= N)
        {
        
            //has the cell been visited yet?
            if(!board[newLine][newRow])
            {

                //recursion until 63th move
                if(moveNumber == max_moves || knight(newLine, newRow, moveNumber+1))
                {
                    printf("Move %d: from %c-%d to %c-%d ", moveNumber, cells[row-1], line, cells[newRow-1], newLine);
                    boardDisplay(newLine, newRow);
                    return 1;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    
    // free last visited cell, if there's no move possible anymore
    board[line][row] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `fflush`? If `boardDisplay` is graphical, you need to provide necessary context.

Comment: I just updated the info on this, thanks for the heads up. I can't use fflush, since there is no stream output (yet). Problem for now is, that the for-loop will run until it found 63 valid moves to solve the tour, then prints the results. Could I leave the code like that and implement a stream output that works already?

Comment: You could cheat and store all the moves in a dynamic array, and then at the end animate it.

Comment: Why would I want a dynamic array for this, as the loop always has 63 moves to print? This would be a neat little "cheat", probably the best solution for my code but ultimately I would like to see all moves taken, including the reverted moves ruled out through recursion. I was hoping I could somehow redirect data to a live stream, but I guess I need to change my general logic to achieve real time output.